# Visual Studio 2010 Setup MSI how to add content file's path to registry

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installscript-msi

Is there a simple way to add one or more content files path's to the registry under the manufacturers's program file path for the current user?  I was able to do this for the executable file but not for any of the added content files.

Comment: This seems a little unclear (to me). Do you just want to write to the registry? Can you give a little more detail to what you are trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to explain what I wanted in the title, and fill in the details in the body of the message, but it didn't work out so well.  I just want to add registry entries at install time.  Usually most of the security is granted during install, and its not guaranteed that it would work after install to set up registry entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put the registry entries in the registry editor.  I also had to use the using statement and place .net code to add registries within the using statement else it lost context.